# How to hide EDGE icon from statusbar in Android 5.1?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, notification-icons

After 5.1 upgrade this EDGE with a red circle appeared in the statusbar. It's useless and the size is wrong. How do I remove or hide it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is your phone rooted? And please add your phone model. And this will be displayed if you turn on the mobile data. To hide the icon you need to turn off the mobile data.

Comment: It's Moto X (1 gen.). Updated to 5.1 a week ago. Not rooted. Mobile data is turned off already. I guess that's why there's a red circle.

Comment: Oh. You didn't mentioned that earlier. I guess it's only with 5.1 even if the data is off.